# how can i change fontcolor and font type of my listview

Tags: java, android, xml

I have one activity that contains text view, buttons, spinner and list view 
my main XML file contains :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffff00"
tools:context="com.example.taxitabriz.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#996600"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#996600"
        android:text="@string/exit"
        android:background="@drawable/backbutton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#996600"
        android:text="@string/about"
        android:background="@drawable/backbutton" />

</LinearLayout>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_weight="49.94" >
</ListView>
```

and part of my java code is here:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> ard=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,s1);
    sp.setAdapter(ard);
    lv1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> ard1=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,s1);
    lv1.setAdapter(ard1);
```

but i can't change font color or font type in list view or spinner. how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a CustomListAdapter.

```
private class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private int id;
    private List <String>items ;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId , List<String> list ) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);           
        mContext = context;
        id = textViewResourceId;
        items = list ;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View mView = v ;
        if(mView == null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mView = vi.inflate(id, null);
        }

        TextView text = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if(items.get(position) != null )
        {
            text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            text.setText(items.get(position));
            text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
            int color = Color.argb( 200, 255, 64, 64 );
                text.setBackgroundColor( color );

        }

        return mView;
    }

}
```

The list item looks like this (custom_list.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="20px" android:paddingTop="10dip" android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Use the TextView api's to decorate your text to your liking

and you will be using it like this

```
listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(YourActivity.this , R.layout.custom_list , mList);
mListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. in this method, how can i use OnClickListener method for manage selected item?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use androids simple list layout, [we see that they declare their textview's identifier as such](https://code.google.com/p/pdn-slatedroid/source/browse/trunk/eclair/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_dropdown_item_1line.xml?r=44):

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

So just make your custom adapter, inflate their layout & find that text view's id.  Something like the following:

```
    public final class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {  

    private Context context;
    ViewHolder holder; 
    private ArrayList<String> messages;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data) {

        this.context = context;
        this.messages = data;
        Log.d("ChatAdapter", "called constructor");

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.message = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.text1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        holder.message.setText(data.get(position));
        holder.message.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

        // don't do this, remember the face variable once just showing explicitly for u
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HandmadeTypewriter.ttf"); 

        holder.message.setTypeface(face); 
        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView message;
    }
}
```

Edit: The following is how you would use the custom array adapter in your activity.

```
// I'm not sure if your sp or lv1 wants the adapter, but
// whatever you require your list view's data to be just 
// set the custom adapter to it
CustomAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, s1);
lv1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1)
lv1.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,but how can i use this class in my mainactivity.java class? and also where i create xml file that you write in above?

Comment: instead of instantiating an ArrayAdapter<T> use this custom adapter above. `CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getBaseContext(), s1); mListView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: You don't have to create the xml file since it is android's xml file.  It is already available to you.  I just referenced it to show you how you can get finer control of the text.  I'll edit the answer to show how you can use this in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, add a ListView item in xml，at `res/layout/list_item1.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/text1"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

    android:textColor="#0000ff"



   android:testStyle="italic"

    android:gravity="center_vertical"

    android:paddingLeft="6dip"

    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

/>
```

then,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> ard=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,s1);
sp.setAdapter(ard);
lv1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayAdapter<String> ard1=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,s1);// **change R.layout.list_item1**
lv1.setAdapter(ard1);
```

Comment: thank you.it works! but can u tell me how can i change font of this text view ? @vic_chen

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the .ttf file of font(which you want to add ) in **asstes/fonts/** folder and write code in onCreate method like below. i have puted **Chalkduster.ttf** in my **asstes/fonts/** folder

```
TextView txttest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txttest);
Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/Chalkduster.ttf");
txttest.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

Comment: I know that, but in this case, it doesn't work. maybe reason is that text view used by layout

Comment: where you have added code of custom font ? have to add this code in adapter's getview() method

Comment: thank you for the answer.I want add custom font to the code of vic_chen answered in this Question.how can i do that?

Comment: you have to create custome adapter like Arun Chand 's answer and then you can add this code

Comment: for which control you have to handle OnClickListener ?? textview?

Comment: selected item from listview

Answer (score 0):

You can handle clicks of selected item by write code just like below

```
ListView lvNews = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNews);
lvNews.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
          // Write your code here    
            //int newsId = newsArray.get(position).getId();
            //Intent i = new Intent(NewsListActivity.this,
            //      NewsDetailActivity.class);
            //i.putExtra(Constants.NEWS_ID, newsId);
            //i.putExtra("isFromNotification", false);
            //startActivity(i);

        }

    });
```